# How do I get React-Native working on my Mac?

Tags: reactjs, react-native-ios

I am unable to get the default "awesomeproject" react-native app working on my new Mac/IOS simulator.

I have installed all the prerequisites on my new mac as listed here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html.

After installing everything I run

`sudo react-native init awesomeproject`.

This seems to work correctly.
I then cd to `awesomeproject` and run

`sudo react-native run-ios`

It eventually builds "successfully" and launches the iPhone simulator.
It launches a new terminal for the packager and here it shows loading dependency / graph: done. But it does show a watchman ERROR. See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kuc9H.png).

After this, nothing happens. It doesn't launch/install the app on the simulator. The terminal that I ran `react-native run-ios` is at the command prompt.

I have looked at the troubleshooting guide and other posts, but can't see what I'm missing? I am just trying to do the basic 101 of getting this working on a mac.

I'm running

- MacOS: 10.14.5
- React-Native version 0.59.9
- react-native-cLI: 2.0.1
- Xcode 10.2.1
- Node: 10.16.0

Answer (score 0):

Either create project again without sudo and run it without sudo or you need to run watchman with sudo permissions. I would suggest creating project again. Please avoid using sudo as much as you can. Thanks

Comment: I finally decided to contact Apple about this, and low and behold, seem like there is file permissions bug in the latest release! It was driving me crazy...but after working with support, they directed me to this article on how to resolve. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538 . It reset permissions, and then presto...everthing works fine now.